# Showing a rational function takes on each of its values the same number of times except finitely many

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ : $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$    $\rightarrow$  $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is a nonconstant rational function. How can one show that $f$ takes on each of its values the same number of times, with the exception of finitely many such values? (Here we are not considering multiplicities).

I have been thinking about this for a while and cannot come up with a reasonable way to attack the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: ${p(z)\over q(z)}=c$ if and only if $p(z)-cq(z)=0.$  With at most one exception, this is a polynomial equation of the same degree for every $c$, so the question is, how many times can it have multiple roots?

Answer (score 5):

Write $f(z)=g(z)/h(z)$ where $g$ and $h$ are polynomials with no common factor.
For $a\in\Bbb C$ we are counting the number of solutions to $f(z)=a$, that is
to $g(z)-ah(z)=0$. Let $d$ be the maximal degree of $g$ and $h$.
With at most one exception, $g(z)-ah(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$. It has
exactly $d$ zeroes, unless its discriminant vanishes. But its discriminant is a
polynomial in $a$, so either has finitely many zeroes (which is what we want),
or is identically zero. In the latter case, $g(z)-ah(z)$ has a non-trivial factor
over the field $\Bbb C(a)$ of rational functions in $a$. That entails
$g(z)-ah(z)$ being reducible as a polynomial in two variables. But that is
only possible if $g$ and $h$ have a common factor.